# MySQL: Get all columns except one, when Joining Table

Tags: javascript, node.js, join, sequelize.js

how can i get all columns in my joined users table except one column.

I want the `password` attribute/column to **NOT** appear in the Promise respond. That doesn't work, as i am calling
`attributes: { exclude: ['password'] }` 
on 
`DBTweet` which hasn’t the property password. The joined Table `DBUser` has that.

That's my current code. I'm using the Sequelize ORM

```
DBTweet.findAll({ include: [DBUser, DBComment], attributes: { exclude: ['password'] }})
.then(tweets => {
    res.status(200).json(tweets)
})
.catch(err => {
    printC(err)
    res.status(500).json({ error: err })
})
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

That was my solution:

```
DBTweet.findAll({ include: [{ model: DBUser, attributes: { exclude: ['password'] } }, DBComment]})
```